# Hive permissions on view not inherited in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I've parquet table `test_table` created in Hive. The location of one of the partitions is `'/user/hive/warehouse/prod.db/test_table/date_id=20210701'`

Created the view based on this table:

```
create view prod.test_table_vw as
select date_id, src, telephone_number, action_date, duration from prod.test_table
```

Then granted select privilege to some role:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE prod.test_table_vw TO ROLE data_analytics;
```

Then user with this role trying to query this data using `spark.sql()` from pyspark:

```
sql = spark.sql(f"""SELECT DISTINCT phone_number
            FROM prod.test_table_vw
            WHERE date_id=20210701""")
sql.show(5)
```

This code returns permission denied error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o138.collectToPython.
: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=keytabuser, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/hive/warehouse/prod.db/test_table/date_id=20210701":hive:hive:drwxrwx--x
```

I can't grant select rights for this table due to some sensitive fields in it, that's why I created view with limited list of columns.

**Questions:**

Why Spark ignores Hive's select permissions on view? And how to resolve this issue?

Comment: looks like it's Spark's limitation: https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-interaction-with-hive-views.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Spark's limitation:

> When a Spark job accesses a Hive view, Spark must have privileges to
> read the data files in the underlying Hive tables. Currently, Spark
> cannot use fine-grained privileges based on the columns or the WHERE
> clause in the view definition. If Spark does not have the required
> privileges on the underlying data files, a SparkSQL query against the
> view returns an empty result set, rather than an error.

Reference [link](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-interaction-with-hive-views.html).